# Rotating Star Field | Immitating 3D Space on a 2D Plane

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I am working to simulate a 3D star field on a 2 dimensional surface where the viewer can turn in only the x direction. With a normal 2D star field of course you could simply modify X / Y positions of the stars to simulate movement; but what I am looking to find is a clearly defined model where the velocities of the stars give the illusion of rotating around the view.

Below is an example of what I mean. Where `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` are all star depths that wrap around the viewer. The wrapping effect (and warping) is where I am stuck.

[image: 3D View]

There are two approaches I am considering, but am currently working toward the first since it appears to be the more attainable of the two.

1. as stars get closer to the edge where motion is occurring, speed up their velocities.
2. as stars get closer to the top and bottom of the screen, the stars curve inward.

or

1. use some sort of "lense effect" (matrix projection magic?) where stars appear to curve around the screen. Not sure how to go about this one.

Part of my problem is not knowing the exact terminology I'm looking for here. I'm a programmer, not a mathematician and I believe this question may fall more so into the latter realm. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889513/canvas-rotating-star-field) but I don't particularly like the solution in terms of the visualized result, so I'm curious if there is anyone out there with alternative solutions.

Comment: I added working C++ example for the projection approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with such approach then circular trajectories does not feel right ... I would try something like rounded diamond shape:

[image: trajectory]

You can use [cubics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214) for this (the blue points are the control points of interpolation cubic) that you init at start when new star is born. And then just iterate its parameter `t` from -1 to +2 ... or use 3 consequent cubics (piecewise interpolation)

However to be **much closer to real 3D** simply move your stars in **straight lines** anti parallel to ship movement and simply project their position based on distance to ship `d`:

```
// camera basis vectors
X = vec3(-sin(yaw),0.0,+cos(yaw)); // view right direction (or left)
Y = vec3(        0,  1,        0); // view up direction (or left)
Z = vec3( cos(yaw),0.0, sin(yaw)); // view forward direction
// camera local coordinates assuming its placed at (0,0,0)
x' = dot(vec3(x,y,z),X);
y' = dot(vec3(x,y,z),Y);
z' = dot(vec3(x,y,z),Z);
// perspective projection
d=c1/max(c0,abs(z));
x' *= d;
y' *= d;
```

Where `yaw` is turn angle , `(x,y,z)` is star coordinate and `c0` is min distance constant to avoid division by zero, `c1` is scaling constant like `zoom` ... You just generate radom star positions around your ship and iterate their `z` coordinate once it crosses some threshold remove that star and generate another one ...

Here small C++/VCL example of this:

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include "GLSL_math.h"
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/71950012/2521214
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int stars=500;
vec3 star[stars];
float yaw=0.0;          // camera view angle
float forw=0.0;         // ship movement angle
float speed=0.02;
float dyaw=0.0;         // camera turning speed
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void stars_init()
    {
    int i;
    vec3 p;
    Randomize();
    for (i=0;i<stars;i++)
        {
        p=vec3(Random(),Random(),Random()); // range < 0, 1>
        p=p+p-vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);                // range <-1,+1>
        star[i]=p;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void stars_update()
    {
    int i;
    vec3 p;
    // update camera direction
    yaw=fmod(yaw+dyaw,2.0*M_PI);
    // ship speed vector
    vec3 dp=speed*vec3( cos(forw),0.0, sin(forw));
    // process stars
    for (i=0;i<stars;i++)
        {
        p=star[i]-dp;                           // apply speed
        while (length(p)>1.0)                   // if out of range
            {
            // create new star
            p=vec3(Random(),Random(),Random()); // range < 0, 1>
            p=p+p-vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);            // range <-1,+1>
            }
        star[i]=p;                              // store new position
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void stars_draw()
    {
    int i,xx=0,yy=0;
    vec3 X,Y,Z;
    float x,y,z,d;
    // camera basis vectors (3x3 rotation matrix)
    X = vec3(-sin(yaw),0.0,+cos(yaw)); // view right direction (or left)
    Y = vec3(        0,  1,        0); // view up direction (or left)
    Z = vec3( cos(yaw),0.0, sin(yaw)); // view forward direction
    // stars
    for (i=0;i<stars;i++)
        {
        // camera local coordinates assuming its placed at (0,0,0)
        x = dot(star[i],X);
        y = dot(star[i],Y);
        z = dot(star[i],Z);
        // behind camera?
        if (z<0) continue;
        // perspective projection
        d=200.0/max(0.001,fabs(z));
        x*=d; xx=Main->xs2+x;
        y*=d; yy=Main->ys2-y;
        // screen cliping & render pixel
        if ((xx>=0)&&(xx<Main->xs)&&(yy>=0)&&(yy<Main->ys))
         Main->pyx[yy][xx]=0x00FFFFFF;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    double x,y,z,r=5,*p;
    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    // stars
    stars_update();
    stars_draw();
    Caption=floor(yaw*180.0/M_PI);

    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    pyx=NULL;
    stars_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;  xs2=xs>>1;
    ys=ClientHeight; ys2=ys>>1;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    pyx=new int*[ys];
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(int*) bmp->ScanLine[y];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
    {
    if (Key==37) dyaw=-2.0*M_PI/180.0;
    if (Key==39) dyaw=+2.0*M_PI/180.0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
    {
    if (Key==37) dyaw=0.0;
    if (Key==39) dyaw=0.0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where `Main->xs,Main->ys` is the resolution of window `Main->xs2,Main->ys2` is half of it (center of screen) and `Main->pyx[y][x]` is direct pixel access to my backbuffer bitmap... The only important stuff are `star_init,star_update,star_draw` functions just change the VCL rendering to your kind ... The camera turning is controled by `dyaw` variable set by keyboard events ... The vecto rmath is GLSL like syntax but you can use any(like GLM) even hardcode as I do not use any wild stuff ...

Here preview for 90 deg rotations:

[image: preview]

just play with the constants to match your needs and screen resolution ...

This approach can use any rotation not just `yaw` ... Now you can play with star colors You can use this:

- [Star B-V color index to apparent RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214)

And add red/blue shift based on `z = dot(star[i],Z);` speed for thet you can use this:

- [RGB values of visible spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214)

You can also render Lines instead of dots to get the feeling of different speeds

Comment: I appreciate the in depth post here Spektre. Some food for thought on how to do the forward movement for sure. Although I am not convinced it solves my particular problem regarding the simulated rotation - it's hard for me to view the gif you posted with the fast frame rate - but the stars don't appear to "curve" as I was describing. I will give it a try though on my end and take a look at the results. :)

Comment: @Durgal the GIF is choppy as my grabber directly encodes instead of lazy encode (and my PC is pretty old so that is best it can do)... the real thing is smooth and its not an approximation is real 3D perspective projection I used 60 deg FOVx if you want more curved view then do a fisheye so increase your FOVx to bigger angles like 90-120 deg ...